# Why was I just awared two more Marshal badges?

Tags: bug

I've had the Marshal badge for a while. It just awarded it to me two more times.

So my profile says I have 5 gold badges, but when I look at them I only have Fanatic, one Famous Question and Marshal.

Comment: Same here, [got 2 notifications](http://i.stack.imgur.com/3n8Fa.png), actual badge count hasn't changed, nor should it have.